# Custom literal works with long double but not double, and with pass by value but not pass by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, literals, constexpr, user-defined-literals

I'm experimenting with C++ custom literals. I'm finding it strange that the simple function below stops working when I change the type from `long double` type to `double`, or when try to pass by reference.

At first I thought it had to do with the use of `constexpr` but that does not seem to be the case, as both of these work fine if it's not on an `operator ""`, and removing the `constexpr` from the `operator ""` does not remove the error.

Are these well-thought-out decisions in the design of the language, or just nuances that my compiler (gcc 4.8.2) can't deal with?

```
// Conversion function, works fine with both long double and
// double, and with or without pass by reference.
constexpr long double to_deg (const long double& deg)
{
    return deg*M_PI/180.0;
}

// Custom literal with long double types and pass by value,
// works fine.
constexpr long double operator "" _deg (long double deg)
{
    return deg*M_PI/180.0;
}

// Custom literal with double types, gives "Invalid argument list."
// error.
constexpr double operator "" _deg (double deg)
{
    return deg*M_PI/180.0;
}

// Custom literal with pass by reference, gives "Invalid argument list." 
// error. Removing the const does not remove the error.
constexpr long double operator "" _deg (const long double& deg)
{
    return deg*M_PI/180.0;
}
```

Comment: Because the language says that `double` as a parameter is not valid and that references aren't either. I'm not sure why you really need that to change.

Comment: @chris It's not that I really need to change it, I'm just experimenting :). OK, I found the "only long double" specification, but I can't find anything about no references.

Comment: The standard lists the set of valid choices. References are not in there. For a perhaps more succinct version, you can try a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: @chris & quantdev Thanks! I'm not very familiar with interpreting the standard, so it did not occur to me that if a reference is not explicitly stated there, it's not allowed. I get it now.

Comment: Note that the type of the constant `180.0` is `double`. To use genuine `long double` constants add postfix `L`: `180.0L`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ Standard, section § 13.5.8 ( User-defined literals), lists all the valid types :

> The declaration of a literal operator shall have a
>   parameter-declaration-clause equivalent to one of the following:
>
> - const char*
> - unsigned long long int
> - long double
> - char
> - wchar_t
> - char16_t
> - char32_t
> - const char*, std::size_t
> - const wchar_t*, std::size_t
> - const char16_t*, std::size_t
> - const char32_t*, std::size_t

Neither `double` or `double&` , `const long double&` are listed here : so they are not allowed.

Comment: A parameter list of `const long double` is equivalent to a parameter list of `long double`.

Comment: For any reason double is excluded?